# ios User Prompt when making outgoing call via URL Scheme 10.2+

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-foundation

It appears that Apple have changed the behaviour when making a phone call via the URL Scheme.  We currently use this code to initiate a phone call:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "tel://011111111111")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL()
```

Prior to iOS 10.2, this immediately launched the dialler and placed the phone call.  It appears that this has now changed, and the user receives a prompt to confirm to make the phone call.  It appears tel:// is behaving more like telprompt://.  This is despite the official Apple URL Scheme document (last updated 2015) mentioning that user interaction is not required if a tel:// URL is opened from a native app.

Does anyone know if (a) this is new, expected behaviour and/or (b) if there is another way around this to initiate a phone call, without prompting the user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately the version 10.3 to restricted the direct calls phone and facetime.

Check yourself:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-10.3/

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT207617